# Adding an additional page to end of a Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report for orders and I'd like to add an additional page at the end that states the orders' Terms & Conditions. Can someone help me?

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but it keep all my header report, i want just blank page when i can add my terms

Answer (score 5):

In your report footer, set it to create a new page before it is printed (In 'Section Expert', select the Report Footer -> 'Paging' tab -> Check 'New Page Before' checkbox). Throw your Terms & Conditions into the Report Footer section.

If you already have a Report Footer that you want to keep, just split the footer into two sections (Right-click the Report Footer section -> 'Insert Section Below') and follow the same procedure for the newly created section.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but it keep all my header report, i want just blank page when i can add my terms.

Comment: @Aissam I don't understand what you mean. Following the above directions will give you one extra page at the end of the report.

Comment: yes i follow the steps at the bottom, it add a page in the end of my report, but it keeps all my forms, header, for i want just blank page where can i add a text field without header and content of my report.

Comment: @Aissam Ah, ok. You can selectively suppress any section you don't want to appear on the last page (Page Header, Page Footer, for example) by adding this suppression formula to those sections: `pagenumber=totalpagecount`.

Comment: it works, but if i have for exemple 3 generate report, the 1/3 , 2/3, appear but the 3/3 not display because the pagenumber=totalpagecount.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a **complete** new page to the end of your Crystal report just make 2 subreports inserted into one main report with Details a and b.

To do that:

1. Make the two subreports and save them;

   2. Make a new main report and insert another Details section(Report->Section expert..., select Details - >Insert)
   3. Onto Details a insert 1st subreport
   4. Onto Details b insert 2nd subreport
   5. Right click on 1st subreport -> Change Subreport links: select each Report fields and transfer them on the right side(Fields to
      link to), click on the right side on each parameter (named like
      ?@Parameter1) and select the coresponding parameter.
   6. Repeat the previous step for the 2nd subreport
   7. Report->Section expert..., click on the Details b and check New page before.

That would be all.

Comment: It's a bit poor that you have to revert to sub-reports to achieve this functionality.  Crystal Reports certainly has its limitations!! :-/

Comment: While trying this, I note that the down-side of burying your reports into sub-reports, is that you lose formatting on the lower-level reports.  For example, my section-footers no longer pull to the bottom of the page in the final output.  I presume that this is because the sub-report doesn't recognise that it's reached the bottom of the page within the context of being in the higher-level report (where a page-ending event hasn't occurred.