# attach extra additional pages at the end of crystal report file

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm designing a **crystal report** and having some trouble while adding extra pages at the end of the report.

The crystal report is generated from database and the additional pages are **.doc** files which I need to attach to that report.

Can anybody guide me on how to do this?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232239/adding-an-additional-page-to-end-of-a-crystal-report

Comment: @Hardik Vinzava following the link footer is repeated on every page.But rather i need at the end of report.

Comment: put in report footer rather than page footer !! report footer will only display on particulate page !!

Answer (score -1):

Put it in the report footer rather than the page footer. Report footer will only display on particular page.

Comment: you can format the same in crystal design as docx file design

Comment: Is their any option available in crystal report where i can attach the  extra pages from other sources like PDF dynamically. ?

Comment: You can insert the PDF in crystal report.

Insert -> OLE Object 

select Adobe Acrobat Document and select the pdf you want to show.

Comment: Using OLE Object first page is displayed in image format. But here i want where and PDF/doc file is available and i need to add that files to that report as an extra pages in same format.

Comment: I need to have a different page that always shows up at the end of the report from PDF or doc where if the files content are changed then it should auto reflect the report.